# Transforming Javascript to React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wrote some simple javascript which transitions a div around on mouseover events using the getBoundingClientRect() method.

```
iconsArray.forEach((icon) => {
icon.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
        const leftOfIcon = this.getBoundingClientRect().left;
        const topOfIcon = this.getBoundingClientRect().top;
        textBox.style.setProperty('transform', `translate(${leftOfIcon}px, ${topOfIcon - 20}px)`);
})
```

My project is now being wrote in React so i need to convert this JS to something that is workable in React. Feeling a little lost.

Any advice is greatly appreciated. I don't think its that tricky. But fairly new to React.

JS Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/harrydry/m5k29htt/13/

Comment: Well it can be broken down in a few steps, namely: Create a component, that holds the icons, add a general `onMouseOver` to the wrapper and use `event.target` instead of `this`. That also means, that you don't need to iterate over all icons

Comment: thanks lumino, i've started implementing this and it looks good. 
my only problem being, event.target logs the whole wrapper, as well as the specific icon which is hovered over ? 

I need it to just target the children?

Comment: Yes, you need to filter out the container. When you hover over a child, `target` holds the child element and no longer the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a simple **stateless** React approach. I use a `data` attribute, just to determine if something is an icon or not to filter out the container:

```js
function IconWrapper( props ) {
  let ref;
  
  const mouseOverCallback = ( e ) => {
    // Filter all elements, that are not an icon
    if ( !e.target.getAttribute( 'data-icon' ) ) {
      return;
    }
    
    // Get bounding rect
    const boundingBox = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    console.log( 'left', boundingBox.left );
    console.log( 'top', boundingBox.top );
    
    ref.style.transform = `translate(${ boundingBox.left }px, ${ boundingBox.top - 20 }px)`;
  };
  
  return (
    <div className="container" onMouseOver={ mouseOverCallback }>
      { null /* Add reference of textBox for later use */ }
      <div className="textBox" ref={ dom => ref = dom }>textbox</div>
      
      { null /* Iterate over icons */ }
      { props.icons.map( ( icon, index ) => (
        <span data-icon key={ index }>{ icon }</span>
      ) ) }
    </div>
  );
}

function App( props ) {
  return (
    <div>
      { null /* Add IconWrapper with some icons */ }
      <IconWrapper icons={ [ 'icon1', 'icon2', 'icon3' ] } />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render( <App />, document.getElementById( 'app' ) );
```

```css
.container {
  background: lightgreen;
  padding-top: 2em;
}

.container span {
  background: lightblue;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 2px;
}

.textBox {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: transform .25s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Maybe this is not the best solution or a pure React solution, but is is quite simple. A more React*ish* solution would be to provide a class, changing the state for the text box.

Comment: solution looks great. Thanks a lot. I'm just trying to implement it into my own example now.

Comment: nice edit man, thanks a lot. Ended up going with this. 

yeah, i agree im not sure its 'best practice'. I struggle with animations in React so fairly happy with this.